# WPF: Instantiating a new window/dialog causes >unrelated< list binding to stop updating

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dialog, viewmodel

**SOLVED**

My problem is a little weird and i'm not even sure why opening a window should have any effect at all on my list binding, so little hard to explain, so here is a video showing what happens:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZ03l8OHEY4

I have 2 Pages, Start Page and Main Page. In Start Page user can select between (supported)devices detected on COM ports. When a device is clicked, the program reads the device and creates a view model list (asynchronously with BackgroundWorker) based on the data on the device, here i also instantiate and show a loading window/dialog. When clicking the device again the program then goes to Main Page and displays the view model list as a view list (with ItemsControl in xaml) that was created for this device.

So far everything works fine.
However, if i have 2 devices a problem occurs if i do A and B but not when i do C. And A and B both works if i do not instatiate the loading window/dialog, i demonstrate this last in the youtube video(it also breaks if i instatiate but do not .Show()).

A) The sameway i said as above, then i go back to Start Page then reads and opens the other device. (this is the second thing i show in the youtube video)

B) The sameway i said as above, then i read and open the other device without going back to start page.

C) Instead, read both devices before opening any of them (stay on Start Page), then open the first device, then open the second device. (This is the first thing i show in the youtube video)

[Top image is showing that the displayed list is the same as the list that is actually in the memory of the computer. Bottom image shows what happens when doing like described in B. As you can see the list on screen is different from what the LiveVisualTree says the list actually is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8dcl.png)

When doing A/B the list that is displayed is not updated to the created view model list of the other device (the list of the first device is still shown). The view model list is created correctly (yes, i have double and triple checked) the view list is just not updated. Even if i manually use OnPropertyChanged() for the list.

However, when i do C everything works flawlessly. The view list is updated to display what the view model list contains.

Some code i think is relevant:

**user clicks on device:**

```
    public static void DeviceClick(ComPortVM comPort)
    {

        CurrentComPort = comPort;

        if (comPort.Device == null)
        {
            ShowReadingDeviceDialog(true);

            BackgroundWorker workThread = new BackgroundWorker();
            workThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BackgroundParameterReader_DoWork);
            workThread.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundNewInverter_RunWorkerCompleted);
            workThread.RunWorkerAsync(new ReadParameterArgs(basic, false));
        }
        else
        {
            OpenDevice();
        }
    }
```

*OBS: when commenting out ShowReadingDeviceDialog(true); the problem does not occur and everything works*

**ShowReadingDeviceDialog(true);**

```
    private static void ShowReadingDeviceDialog(bool show)
    {
        if (ReadingDeviceDialog != null)
        {
            ReadingDeviceDialog.Close();
        }

        if (show)
        {
            MainWindow.instance.IsEnabled = false;
            MainWindow.SetCursor(System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait);
            ReadingDeviceDialog = new OpeningInverterDialog();
            ReadingDeviceDialog.Owner = MainWindow.instance;
            ReadingDeviceDialog.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MainWindow.SetCursor(System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow);
            MainWindow.instance.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

*OBS: when not instantiating a new ReadingDeviceDialog the problem does not occur and everything works*

**OpenDevice**

```
    private static void OpenDevice()
    {
        if (!isOpening)
        {
            isOpening = true;
            if (!InfoPanels.ContainsKey(CurrentDevice))
            {
                InfoPanels.Add(CurrentDevice, new InfoPanelVM());
                InfoPanels[CurrentDevice].SetUp(CurrentDevice);
            }
            MainViewModel.instance.RefreshInfoPanel();

            startDelay.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            startDelay.Start();
        }
    }
```

**startDelay Tick**

```
    private static void StartDelay_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow.OpenPage("MainPage");

        if (!paramTabBars.ContainsKey(CurrentDevice))
        {
            MainPage.ClearFrame();
            paramTabBars.Add(CurrentDevice, new ParamTabBarVM());
            ParamTabBar.SetUp(CurrentDevice);
        }
        else
        {
            ParamTabBar.OpenTab("");
        }

        startDelay.Stop();
        isOpening = false;
        ShowReadDeviceDialog(false);
        MainViewModel.instance.RefreshParamTabBtns();
    }
```

*It's the ParamBarTab that contains the list that causes problems, called ParamTabBtns. Using MainViewModel.instance.RefreshParamTabBtns(); simply uses OnPropertyChanged(ParamTabBtns) for the currently selected Device, this fixed a similiar problem i had with the view list not updating to fit view model list. However this fix does not work now when i instantiate a loading dialog window.*

Since the binding had worked all the time before i started instantiating a loading dialog i do not think the problem is in XAML, so i won't bother posting that to.

I know this question maybe weridly asked, but since i have no clue on what going on i don't really know what else information i should provide. I'm mostly just hoping for someone giving me ideas as what kind of thing that might possibly be the thing i should try to find, but right now i'm totally blind.

**Edit:** I'm starting to suspect it's a bug in WPF and not on my side? LiveVisualTree the DataContext gives me the right list, but that list is not shown on screen. Screen cap with green arrows is when everything works, with red arrows is when i did like in A. The list to the side that says 15 in length is the list that is supposed to be shown in the application, yet it isnt.
Isn't LiveVisualTree supposed to show me the binding? If the binding works in LiveVisualTree isn't it supposed to work in the application too? Isn't that what LiveVisualTree is used for? Debugging? So shouldnt the bindings in LiveVisualTree reflect the actual bindings happening inside the application?

**Edit 2:** I tried BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization following http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/20/wpf-45-cross-thread-collection-synchronization-redux
However, this had no impact on anything. So it probably isn't threading related either? And it doesnt make sense that it is threading related anyway, since i can change the collection as i please when the dialog window has not been intantiated in scenario A and B. And again, the dialog window has noting the do with the collection (no references, no method calls, no nothing)
[LiveVisualTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsZtC.png)

**EDIT 3, SOLUTION:**
Apparently when using

```
 <Window.DataContext>
     <vm:MainViewModel/>
 </Window.DataContext>
```

WPF creates a new instance of the datacontext, in the constructor of my MainViewModel i had static reference to itself. But when i instantiated a new window that reference got pointed to the newly created datacontext instead, which destroyed the bindings.
To fix this i removed the code from above from all xaml files that had it and instead put this in the construction (code behind)
DataContext = MainViewModel.instance;

Comment: If I had to guess, you are probably just pointing to an device object in a list on the child page and when that child page is recreated the list itself is being recreated and that device object you are pointing to is no longer valid.  You need to copy that selected device object into a new object that is saved on the main page so that the main page can keep the references between calls.   Set a debugger to watch the object and see what happens to the reference as the code is running and you should see the problem.  My guess is you can save the last device right before running the new page.

Comment: Maybe im misunderstanding you, but; I'm unsure what the "child page" is. I have two pages, Main Page and Start Page, both happen in MainWindow. The pages does not contain any data, and no ViewModel, only View for the pages. I have a big "main" class, ComPortManager. In here is a list of all the devices (view models) that, each device view model class contains a ParamTabBtns list (the list that im asking the question about). 

So in the view, (with MainViewModel as datacontext) i'm uing ParamTabsBtns, as binding. Which has Get) "return ComPortManager.ParamTabBar.ParamTabBtns;"

Comment: Also, it seems like if the problem was that the references broke when switching pages, then why would the references not break when i'm not instantiating a dialog? Either way, when i write out the device and its ParamTabsBtns list to Output window in visual studio, it looks fine and is created correctly. So it's not that the reference is point to wrong device or is empty, the View Model is correct.

Comment: You should probably show how you wire up the datacontext for both these pages, you are probably destroying/rebuilding the context each time and thus killing your references.

Comment: For the pages i'm just using <Page.DataContext> <vm:MainViewModel/ </Page.DataContext> at the top of the xaml file.

I made a video to demonstrate what is happening, since it's hard to explain it text. Notice the list that is shown at the top of the screen (gray background, white text) and compare it to the list that is written in the Output window of VS. The list is written once the new Device is "opened" and the loading window is closed and everything is done, the list is the same list that View is binded to.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZ03l8OHEY4

Comment: So ParamTabBar is an observablecollection of ParamTabBtns?

Comment: ParamTabBar is a class that contains an "ObservableCollection<ParamTabButtonVM> paramTabBtns;" aswell as other things. I access it through MainViewModel with "return ComPortManager.ParamTabBar.ParamTabBtns;".

(ComPortManager.ParamTabBar returns: paramTabBars[CurrentInverter];)

Comment: I checked the list in LiveVisualTree, there the binding is working. It is showing me the correct list that is supposed to be shown in the application, yet it isnt for some reason. So if it works in the LiveVisualTree that confirms that it isn't a reference error? And it also makes it seem like this is a bug in WPF and not in my code...?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsZtC.png

Comment: This definitly not related to a WPF bug. Most of the times when people accuse the framework of buggy behavior, the true origin is related to the lack of understanding the framework they are working with. So you better start to investigate your implementation thoroughly instead of assuming a bug. You don't really show much here. You should create a small example that reproduces your issue. This allows us to review your code.

Comment: You should know that `Window.Show` is an "asynchronous" operation and returns immediately (execution continous). Instead of disabling the main window, better show the dialog with a modal behavior: `Window.ShowDialog`. `ShowDialog` will also wait until the dialog is closed. In case you are updating the collection from a background thread you must use the `Dispatcher` to update the collection or register the collection with `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`.

Comment: Also press Crtl+Alt+E and verify that all Common Language Runtime exceptions are enabled. Run the application in debug mode to see if any exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tips, will experiment tomorrow when i get back to work. Just wanted to add that the problem occurs even if i don't use .Show() , problem happens even if i instantiate the window (with new) but does not use Show on the instanse. I do believe the problem is related to the thread. So will check into what you said about the Dispatcher. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization by following http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/20/wpf-45-cross-thread-collection-synchronization-redux 
however, this had no effect on anything. 

I'm still at a complete loss as to why instantiating the dialog (in case A and B but no C) breaks the binding, when the dialog has nothing to do with the binding or list. Nothing that happens in the dialog effects the collection in any way shape or form. So, if the problem is becausen i update the list in another thread, then why can i update the list if i do not instatiate the dialog??

Comment: "You should create a small example that reproduces your issue. This allows us to review your code"
But it is stretching over a vast amount of files and classes. Also the problem occurs when i read from NFO inverters on the COM ports, so unless you have some of those lying around it will be hard for me to send code for you to test. 

I can record a video and like scroll around all the files or something. I donnu.

Comment: Also, why how can LiveVisualTree show a different list when what is actually displayed? Isnt LiveVisualTree supposed to show the binding? And if the binding is displayed correctly in LiveVisualTree shouldnt it work in the application? I've tried to google this question but cant find an answear

Comment: I was thinking i could do a hack solution, in the background thread i save everything in a dummy object that has no bindings to view. Then when background thread is done i just copy the values on the dummy object into the values of the object that is binded to view.

However, it seems like RunWorkerCompleted happens on the main thread, and it is in here that i update the list. So the list >should< be updated on teh main thread right now, yet it is not working.

Can i check which thread a line of code is currently in? Like just put a line of code wherever and outputs which thread?

Comment: Ok, now i'm pretty sure it is not a threading issue. According to Thread.CurrentThread i am in thread ID 1 and IsBackground is False. This must mean i am in the main thread? right? So... this is not a threading problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when using

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

WPF creates a new instance of the datacontext, in the constructor of my MainViewModel i had static reference to itself. But when i instantiated a new window that reference got pointed to the newly created datacontext instead, which destroyed the bindings. To fix this i removed the code from above from all xaml files that had it and instead put this in the construction (code behind):

```
DataContext = MainViewModel.instance;
```

Comment: i wanted to mark this thread/post as solved, thats why i posted this reply. but i guess i have to wait 22 hours for some reason...